# .htaccess url rewrite - remove .php remove www. convert ?id=10 to /10

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

As the title says, I need a quite complex url rewrite mechanism for a web-app as .htaccess rule.
I've searched quite a lot now and tried hundred of different rewrite rules.

So, basically this is what I need:
User goes to: **http://www.site.com/product.php?id=12**
Server should redirect to: **http://site.com/product/12**

Once thing to mention:
not all pages do append id's.
So I also have: **http://www.site.com/some/page.php**
which then should redirect to: **http://site.com/some/page**

or from **http://site.com/anotherone.php** to **http://site.com/anotherone**

You help is much appreciated and thank you a lot in advance for you help!

Comment: Show us at least 1 of those hundred attempts so we can see in which direction you were going.

Comment: @LazyOne I've droped most of them but this: RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)$ $1.php [L] since it was the only what which is at least working "some how"..

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php\?id=([0-9]+)$ http://%1/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Sorry but it's not working?
I went to site.com/product/10 and i got an 404?
same with site.com/some/page or site.com/this
No redirects or url rewriting?

Comment: @blub Your description (the question) and the URL you are trying to go (the comment above) are two COMPLETELY DIFFERENT things -- in your question you are asking to do opposite to `site.com/product/10`. Decide/re-phrase your question first.

Answer (score 0):

I supose that you, previously have this mod_rewrite rule active:

Users goes to http://site.com/product/12 and in the browser is showed this URL, and internaly, and only internaly, server serve http://www.site.com/product.php?id=12

Put the first RewriteCond and Rule this:

```
   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
   RewriteRule ^(\w+)\.php\?id=(\d*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301]
```

And add another to remove the .php when ends with .php

```
   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
   RewriteRule ^(\w+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working too - I'm getting redirected from page.php to page, but it shows me a 404

When I go to site.com/product.php?id=10 it redirects me to */product?id10 and a 404 again :/  am I missing something?