# Convert dynamic urls with GET requests into static pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm detecting parameters through GET request like so:
http://example.com/?id=10

Each of these dynamic pages are like a post with an id of 10

So, when a user is browsing to the page, I want the URL to convert into something like this:
http://example.com/post-title-goes-here

In addition, I'd like the posts to redirect to the link above when they try to browse them like this:
http://example.com/?id=10
OR
http://example.com/10

How do I do this? Can I do this by .htaccess or do I have to use a combination of both .htaccess and php?

Comment: You should start by reading a tutorial on url rewriting and try a few things. It isn't that complicated. Then if you get stuck or don't understand something, seach for it and make a question if you can't find anything.

Comment: On the number its easy. To do `http://example.com/post-title-goes-here` you need your PHP to take the title param and look at a db. Its the same thing as far as the htaccess forwarding to a php and converting the url part to a param, just this time the param is not a number

Comment: @Ben, you lost the url when you copied that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964031/htaccess-url-rewrite-remove-php-remove-www-convert-id-10-to-10

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I already searched around stackoverflow quite a bit. Couldn't find an exact solution.

The link which Ben posted only partly answers my question.

Comment: You are not likely to find something that does exactly what you need to do. But reading a few tutorials and playing around will teach you how. It's not like I'm suggesting to learn an entire language. This is one small subset and should be able to be picked up in an hour for the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012045/htaccess-rewrite-url-like-stackoverflow/22013979?noredirect=1#comment42164314_22013979)** which worked perfectly in my case.